# ARFoundation placing AR-objects from a certain point and saving point to database

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I am new to AR and I hope you guys could give me an idea on where to start.
I want to create a mobile AR application that gives displays information on a wall filled with electronics and pipes. This information should usually be displayed on the same place when starting the app, since the electronics dont move theirselves. From time to time the electronics do get switched up, so I want an admin being able to change the positions of the information in the app. I think that to realize this I need to save the locations to my own database server. I was thinking about using a specific point (that I will call an anchor) and then count length from that point to the onther points. Preferably the AR objects (information) stay in the same place even when the anchor is out of sight, so we could walk around and everything still works fine.
I added an image to clarify my idea, I hope you guys could give me some recommendations on what techniques to use.
This was my first post and I hope the idea is somewhat clear.

[Image to clarify my idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfzsa.png)

Comment: You may find your question gets flagged as too broad. Best thing to do is look at documentation on how AR implements Anchors or see if a tutorial such as this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aq6x0_EcMKY helps your understanding. Try something first.

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-save-3d-objects-position-and-rotation-and-load-them-at-the-exact-place-using-arkit-in-unity.736424/ may also help.

Comment: ARCore or Unity may be overkill for that. Why not just use something with simple edge detection and plop some flat text on the screen relative to it?

Comment: I don't even find a question, starting with *no question mark*. There is [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), narrowing stack**overflow** to asking about problems. [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) urges to *Make sure it’s obvious what you’re trying to get out of the question*.

Comment: That's because they are trolling proverbial trial-balloons that I like shooting my mouth off at, hence the answer with the question mark in it...